# Works in emulator in debug and no-debug, but only in debug on device

Tags: windows-phone-7

I'm developing an app for WP7, but I ran into a problem I haven't seen before. When I build and run it in the emulator, it works as it should both in debug, and no-debug (ctrl-F5). But on the Windows device, it's only working in debug (F5). When i run it on the device without debugging (ctrl-F5), the app starts, but when I get to a button-click, it just exit the app. In the button-click, I load an xml file. The xml file is set to Build Action "Content", Copy to output "Do not copy". Am I doing something wrong? I'm wondering if the following code in the xaml file beeing loaded has something to do with the error:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage 
x:Class="appname.NamesList"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:appname"
xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit"
FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
SupportedOrientations="Portrait" Orientation="Portrait"
mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignHeight="768" d:DesignWidth="480"
shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True">

<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.DataContext>
    <local:MainViewModel />
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.DataContext>

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot"
      Background="Transparent">
    <toolkit:LongListSelector ItemsSource="{Binding Persons}">
        <toolkit:LongListSelector.GroupItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <toolkit:WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </toolkit:LongListSelector.GroupItemsPanel>
        <toolkit:LongListSelector.GroupHeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Border Background="Transparent">
                    <Border Width="75"
                            Height="75"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                            Background="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}">
                        <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                                   Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
                                   Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}"
                                   Text="{Binding Key}" />
                    </Border>
                </Border>
            </DataTemplate>
        </toolkit:LongListSelector.GroupHeaderTemplate>
        <toolkit:LongListSelector.GroupItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Border Width="75"
                        Height="75"
                        Background="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}"
                        IsHitTestVisible="{Binding HasItems}">
                    <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                               Margin="{StaticResource PhoneTouchTargetOverhang}"
                               FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilySemiBold}"
                               FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeExtraLarge}"
                               Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
                               Text="{Binding Key}" />
                </Border>
            </DataTemplate>
        </toolkit:LongListSelector.GroupItemTemplate>
        <toolkit:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Margin="{StaticResource PhoneTouchTargetOverhang}">
                    <HyperlinkButton Name="cmdName" 
                                     Content="{Binding Name}"
                                     Click="cmdName_Click"
                                     Margin="75,0,0,0" 
                                     HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                     FontSize="40" />
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </toolkit:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
    </toolkit:LongListSelector>

</Grid>
```

And the MainViewModel:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
using appname.Helpers;

namespace appname
{
    public class MainViewModel
    {
        public MainViewModel()
        {
            App app = Application.Current as App;

            XmlHelper xmlHelper = new XmlHelper();
            app.persons = xmlHelper.GetPersons(app.gender);
            List<Person> persons = app.persons;


            this.Persons = new LongListCollection<Person,char>(persons, person => person.Name[0]);
        }

        public LongListCollection<Person, char> Persons
        {
            get;
            private set;
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit**
The code for the xml file-reading:

```
 public List<Person> GetPersons(string gender)
    {
        string xmlPath = "";
        if (gender == "Boys")
            xmlPath = @"Resources/Boys/Xml/Names.xml";
        else if( gender == "Girls" )
            xmlPath = @"Resources/Girls/Xml/Names.xml";

        //Uri uri = new Uri(xmlPath, UriKind.Relative);
        StreamResourceInfo sm = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri(xmlPath, UriKind.Relative));
        System.Xml.XmlReader xr = System.Xml.XmlReader.Create(sm.Stream);

        XDocument data = XDocument.Load(xr);



        return (from c in data.Descendants("Person")
                orderby c.Attribute("Name")
                select new Person()
                {
                    Name = c.Element("Name").Value,
                    Description = c.Element("Description").Value,
                    ...
                    HasGraph = c.Element("HasGraph").Value
                }).ToList();
    }
```

**Edit**

```
<Capabilities>
  <Capability Name="ID_CAP_GAMERSERVICES"/>
  <Capability Name="ID_CAP_IDENTITY_DEVICE"/>
  <Capability Name="ID_CAP_IDENTITY_USER"/>
  <Capability Name="ID_CAP_LOCATION"/>
  <Capability Name="ID_CAP_MEDIALIB"/>
  <Capability Name="ID_CAP_MICROPHONE"/>
  <Capability Name="ID_CAP_NETWORKING"/>
  <Capability Name="ID_CAP_PHONEDIALER"/>
  <Capability Name="ID_CAP_PUSH_NOTIFICATION"/>
  <Capability Name="ID_CAP_SENSORS"/>
  <Capability Name="ID_CAP_WEBBROWSERCOMPONENT"/>
  <Capability Name="ID_CAP_ISV_CAMERA"/>
  <Capability Name="ID_CAP_CONTACTS"/>
  <Capability Name="ID_CAP_APPOINTMENTS"/>
</Capabilities>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Oh my god**

I tried starting another app on my phone, and it exited also. So, I rebooted the phone (thought I had done this yesterday..), and it works! I'm sorry for wasting your time!

Regards an embarrased fool!

Comment: If you have enough reputation, you can delete your own question. I would suggest you do that if/when possible.

Comment: Yes Claus, but I have to wait 2 days before I can delete it. Thanks for the help man!

Answer (score 0):

Nothing wrong with the code you posted per say. We would need to see the code for your `XmlHelper` class, to give you details.

However, I suspect you're handling resource management in a wrong way. Also, I would suggest you try and wrap your code in a try / catch, and then use MessageBox.Show with the exception message.

That should at least, ensure if the crash, is or is not, related to a exception.

```
public MainViewModel()
{
    try
    {
        App app = Application.Current as App;

        XmlHelper xmlHelper = new XmlHelper();
        app.persons = xmlHelper.GetPersons(app.gender);
        List<Person> persons = app.persons;


        this.Persons = new LongListCollection<Person,char>(persons, person => person.Name[0]);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Added the try catch, but it's not showing when the app exits. Also added the xml code in the post.

Comment: Then the exit isn't related to any of your code in the `MainViewModel`. Have you uninstalled the application entirely on your device, before re-deploying it?

Comment: Yes. Tried it now, strange, because now the list loaded, and when I click on "A", and then on "N" (random), it exits. And the next time I start it, it exits before the list is loaded. Same thing happend yesterday evening. Strange...!

Comment: Bad dependencies perhaps? What version of the Silverlight Toolkit are you using?

Comment: can you try to add a MessageBox.Show in the Application_UnhandledException handler in the App.cs file ?

Comment: It says version 7.0.0.0 in the property window when i select it in the "References". I just added it via Nuget. In the Nuget it says: Silverlight for Windows Phone Toolkit, Id: SilverlightToolkitWP, Version: 4.2011.11.15

Comment: I tried adding the MessageBox.Show to the App.._Unha...but it didn't show...same thing happens.

Comment: Sounds like a capability problem then! Double check your capabilities in the `WMAppManifest.xml`.

Comment: Not sure what to check, I added the compability list in the org. post, do you see any errors?